# I can not populate my MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I created 3 tables on MySQL DB and want to populate them, but I have an exception. Here it is:

> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'unique_idx'

Maybe someone can tell my what I am duing wrong?

InitialDB:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_roles;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
(
  id         INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  login      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  password   VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  full_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_unique_login_idx ON users (login);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_roles
(
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  role    VARCHAR(45),
  CONSTRAINT user_roles_idx UNIQUE (user_id, role),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (
  id          INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  patronymic VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  mobile_phone_number VARCHAR(15),
  home_phone_number VARCHAR(15),
  address VARCHAR(45),
  email VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_idx ON contacts (user_id);
```

PopulatorDB:

```
DELETE FROM lardi.users;
DELETE FROM lardi.user_roles;
DELETE FROM lardi.contacts;

INSERT INTO lardi.users
  (login,password,full_name) VALUES
  ('Bill', '112233', 'user'),
  ('John', '112233', 'user'),
  ('Mark', '112233', 'user');

INSERT INTO lardi.user_roles
  (role,user_id) VALUES
  ('USER_ROLE',1),
  ('USER_ROLE',2),
  ('ADMIN_ROLE',3);

INSERT INTO lardi.contacts
(first_name, last_name, patronymic, mobile_phone_number, home_phone_number, address, email, user_id) VALUES
  ('Bill','Gates','','+380(66)1234567','','USA','bill@gmail.com', 1),
  ('Mark','Zukenberg','','+380(66)9876543','+380(44)1122334','USA','mark@gmail.com', 1),
  ('Barak','Obama','','+380(99)1234567','','USA','barak@gmail.com', 1),
  ('Michel','Obama','','+380(99)9876543','','USA','michel@gmail.com', 1),
  ('David','Camaron','','+380(50)5557799','+380(44)0000009','UK','david@gmail.com', 2),
  ('Steve','Jobs','','+380(00)1100999','','USA','steve@gmail.com', 2),
  ('Tim','Kuk','','+380(00)2244888','','USA','tim@gmail.com', 2),
  ('Jim','Carry','','+380(69)8881188','+380(44)1111119','USA','jim@gmail.com', 3),
  ('David','Backham','','+380(67)90000001','','UK','david@gmail.com', 3);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_idx ON contacts (user_id);
```

`contacts` Table `user_id` is unique. Then you can't insert duplicate data to `user_id`

Comment: I added this answer first

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_idx ON contacts (user_id);
```

Your `contacts` table has a unique index on `user_id`.

You are trying to insert a load of contacts with the same user id.

Answer (score 0):

You have unique_idx that has to be unique, but you are saving duplicated values with the INSERT INTO lardi.contacts